# Extract AC current from AC/DC current generated by a solar module

Tags: solar-cell

I have a solar module with capacitance in nF range. There is an AC and DC current coming out from the module due to the incident DC and AC light. I would like to treat this like an AC/DC current source in parallel with nF capacitor. I need to measure this AC current (square pulses in the 200-400Hz frequency range) at the output. (or in terms of voltage)

- DC current range: 1 A to 8 A
- AC current range: 5 µA to 80 µA

I cannot connect a large resistor at the output, as my solar module must be maintained at short circuit condition. Also, the circuitry must not depend on the capacitor value.

Comment: Hmm ... what kind of component passes DC but blocks AC?

Comment: What is the frequency range of the AC you're interested in? What kind of measurement accuracy are you looking for?

Comment: This is really unclear - are you trying to measure a small variation superimposed on top of a large current? Why must it be maintained at short-circuit?

Comment: If the solar module must be kept shorted out (for this test), then the tiny capacitance in parallel with it makes no difference.

Comment: @pjc50 Yes, I want to measure the small variation in the current. I am doing a quantum efficiency measurement. So, I have to maintain short circuit condition. I can apply a voltage bias to maintain the module at short circuit condition, but this doesn't mean that I can use a large resistor at the output.

Comment: @SimonB I would like to recorrect my sentence. I can't put the module directly at short circuit condition, but at least then I shouldn't let the output voltage of the module to be very high.

Answer (score 1):

This is the situation you've described so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0QzBv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is your sense resistor, which converts your 5-80 µA AC current into a 5-80 mV AC voltage, which should be easy to measure.

Now, what kind of component can you put at U1 that will pass the DC current, but have minimal effect on the AC measurement?

What effect does C1 have on the measurement?

(Hint: U1 could also be a 4-terminal device, in which case, it could be physically much smaller.)